# Save array to Parse.com

Tags: arrays, json, swift, parse-platform, swift2

I have a boolean array which contains 10 boolean values. I would like to save this array to Parse.com

There is an example on Parse.com, but when I try to save arrays it doesn't really seem to work:

```
var gameScore = PFObject(className:"GameScore")
gameScore["score"] = 1337
gameScore["playerName"] = "Sean Plott"
gameScore["cheatMode"] = false
gameScore.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
  (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
  if (success) {
    // The object has been saved.
  } else {
    // There was a problem, check error.description
  }
}
```

Comment: Where's your boolean array? Example code doesn't have any arrays.

Comment: what is the error? please provide more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
let myBooleanArray = [false,true,false,true,true,false]
let myObject = PFObject(className: "MyObject")
myObject["booleanArrayColumn"] = myBooleanArray
myObject.saveEventually()
```